# LVGL v8.2 on ESP32-S3 colour issue ILI9341 TFT LCD Arduino IDE

Tags: esp32

I have [ILI9341 320x240px TFT LCD screen](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005003943508410.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.145.21ef5c5fPSOh1Q&gatewayAdapt=glo2deu) which I am using with ESP32-S3-wroom-1 module.

I have tested with TFT_eSPI and works fine, but when using LVGL, I am seeing weird artefacts on the edges.
[image]

I am using Arduino IDE

Started off the sketch from

https://github.com/lvgl/lvgl/blob/master/examples/arduino/LVGL_Arduino/LVGL_Arduino.ino

Havent changed sketch file much.

I am using LVGL latest v8.2.0

```c
/*====================
   COLOR SETTINGS
 *====================*/

/*Color depth: 1 (1 byte per pixel), 8 (RGB332), 16 (RGB565), 32 (ARGB8888)*/
#define LV_COLOR_DEPTH 16

/*Swap the 2 bytes of RGB565 color. Useful if the display has an 8-bit interface (e.g. SPI)*/
#define LV_COLOR_16_SWAP 1

/*Enable features to draw on transparent background.
 *It's required if opa, and transform_* style properties are used.
 *Can be also used if the UI is above another layer, e.g. an OSD menu or video player.*/
#define LV_COLOR_SCREEN_TRANSP 1

/* Adjust color mix functions rounding. GPUs might calculate color mix (blending) differently.
 * 0: round down, 64: round up from x.75, 128: round up from half, 192: round up from x.25, 254: round up */
#define LV_COLOR_MIX_ROUND_OFS 0

/*Images pixels with this color will not be drawn if they are chroma keyed)*/
#define LV_COLOR_CHROMA_KEY lv_color_hex(0x00ff00)         /*pure green*/
```

`LV_COLOR_SCREEN_TRANSP 1` was originally 0 changing it did not change anything.

I am following the FAQ which mentions

> 1.6.7 Why I see nonsense colors on the screen?
> Probably LVGL's color format is not compatible with your displays color format. Check LV_COLOR_DEPTH in
> lv_conf.h.
> If you are using 16 bit colors with SPI (or other byte-oriented interface) probably you need to set LV_COLOR_16_SWAP
> 1 in lv_conf.h. It swaps the upper and lower bytes of the pixels.

as you can see above in the config, the values are as recommended.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had to disable `LV_COLOR_16_SWAP`
I had been trying with different colour depths and everything else, I still cannot see gradients drawn properly, but the colours seem to be correct now.[image]

Comment: I am encountering the exact same problem, using the same ESP32-S3, but using ESP-IDF framework; not Arduino. My solution was exactly the same as yours; comment out the `LV_COLOR_16_SWAP` in the generated `ui.c`. BTW, the project I am working on is here: https://github.com/smeisner/smart-thermostat I am hoping this gets fixed sometime soon!

Comment: BTW, I found this on the SquareLine Studio forum: http://forum.squareline.io/t/when-exporting-let-us-choose-if-we-want-lv-color-16-swap-or-not/1750?u=meisner

Comment: Thanks @SteveMeisner for sharing the link